# Return zero if NULL

Tags: mysql, windows, visual-c++

I have a piece of MySQL that is hitting some empty records, how would I set this to return 0 if NULL?
Thank You!

Tried this:

```
sprintf(queryString, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblURLIP
     WHERE IP = '%s' AND IPStatus = '1' AND IPMax     = '0' 
         AND IPType ='3'", ipSrc);
```

Didn't work:

```
sprintf(queryString, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblURLIP 
          WHERE IP = '%s' AND IPStatus = '1' AND IPMax = '0' 
             AND IPType ='3'", ipSrc,NULL),0);
```

Comment: `COUNT(*)` should return 0 if there were no matching rows. From where do you get the `NULL`?

Comment: Because I was getting Unhandled exception at 0x57088ce4 in lsniff.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can usually wrap things that return NULL in a [`coalesce` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) which gives you the first non-null value:

```
select coalesce (some-nullable-thing, 0 ) from ...
```

However, `count()` should *never* return NULL. If there are no records satisfying the clauses, it should just return 0.

If your problem lies not in the SQL but in the fact that `ipSrc` itself is NULL, this is a simple matter of morphing it before processing it with the `sprintf`.  To convert a NULL to 0 and leave everything else untouched, you can use something like:

```
sprintf (queryString,
    "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblURLIP"
    " WHERE IP = '%s'"
    " AND IPStatus = '1'"
    " AND IPMax = '0'"
    " AND IPType ='3'",
    (ipSrc == NULL) ? "0" : ipSrc);   // <-- conversion happens here.
```

That seems to be your desired behaviour.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear, I only wnat it to return 0 if I get a null back. I'm not looking for NULL. Thanks for the coalesce, will use for future reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet of code you post is pure C (it's obviously building up a query string for SQL, but there's no SQL being done here, just building up a string).

My only interpretation of your question that makes sense to me is that sometimes ipSrc is NULL, sometimes it points to a valid character string.

Assuming that is the case, I think this will do what I think you are asking:

```
sprintf(queryString, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblURLIP
     WHERE IP = '%s' AND IPStatus = '1' AND IPMax     = '0' 
         AND IPType ='3'", ipSrc == 0 ? "0" : ipSrc);
```

The key part is the `? :` operator combination.  If this is too-obfuscated C for your comfort you could also do this:

```
if (ipSrc == 0) // instead of 0 you can use NULL if that better suits your style
    ipSrc = "0";
sprintf(queryString, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblURLIP
         WHERE IP = '%s' AND IPStatus = '1' AND IPMax     = '0' 
             AND IPType ='3'", ipSrc);
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I'm tryimg it now. It seems to be working fine.

Comment: Oops there was a mistake in my second example (in the assignment to ipSrc), now edited to fix